# Is There a Way to let Blender Use More Memory?

Tags: export, collada

First off, I'm not really experienced with Blender.

Someone gave me a really large geometry designed with Blender (~135 Mbytes) which I need to export into the COLLADA format for my work on a thesis.

Unfortunately, when I start the export function, Blender closes after a few seconds and the resulting COLLADA file is not complete. It just ends somewhere after ~20k lines while defining some vertices. It works fine with smaller geometries.

My best guess is, that Blender does not reserve enough memory, gets an out-of-memory-error and closes. I couldn't find any error log. Is there a way display any Blender errors that occured and/or to increase the reserved RAM manually?

I'm using Blender 2.67 on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Welcome to the site :) This question appears to be off-topic as bug reports are considered off-topic on Blender.SE.

Comment: Ah, I do now realize it reads like a bug report. I hoped for something like "no, you can't increase the reserved memory", since i was not able to find any useful informations on google. If it was, I'd go to the Blender site and file a bug report. But for now, I'm not sure if it really is a bug: For example Java apps crashing in Eclipse with out of memory exceptions is not a bug in Eclipse or the JVM.

Comment: if you know how to start blender from the command-line, you can start it with the debug switch `blender --debug-all`. Starting from command-line will leave the command window open while blender prints messages on progress and failures, even if blender.exe closes prematurely. It may be worth [filing a bug report](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/best-place-to-put-bug-reports). COLLADA exporter is still a work in progress, instead of uploading the .blend consider using some service like dropbox

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Now I got a crash.txt, but I can't make anything of it: http://textsave.de/LwJ
Unfortunately, I am not allowed to attach the .blend file in a bug report due to copyright issues.

Comment: A solution to the copyright issue would be to deform the content (geometry and textures) to the extent where it doesn't represent the original model to any meaningful degree. People at the bug tracker are more interested in fixing a potential bug than violating copyright. Yeah that error message doesn't say much.

Comment: I'd like to add, that in version 2.69 the file exports without crashing the program.